# Make image scale with the menu under it

Tags: html, css

I have this wide image in a site's header (`width:100%`)
[image]

Under it, I have a menu (basically a `list` with `li` elements set to `float:left` and `ul` `float:right`).

For a site width of `1868px` I get this correct output:

[image]

But when I **scale to `1280px` this happens:**

[image]

**Can I make the menu scale with the image (keep the same proportions) by using css?**

How can I make the image keep the same proportions on different resolutions?

Comment: Use a background image instead of an image

Comment: Could we see the HTML and corresponding CSS, please?

Comment: @jaunt I'm afraid I can't post the code as it is confidential

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your image as a background image of a div instead of adding it directly as an  tag. Set the background-position: bottom right; and set the div height to the height of your image.

Comment: The same thing happens and I cannot hide the upper part of the menu under the image to get the "curve" effect

Comment: Oh, it worked, I wasn't setting the position! Million thanks! Now the only problem is obtaining the "curvy" effect, as I was setting the z-index of the image to 99 and it was positioned over the menu